# Why is my multi-step SARIMA forecasting returning such good results?

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, forecasting

I've been working on a SARIMA model that could forecast for up to 12 months into the future.

I'm using two functions to perform my forecasting.

The first `auto_sarima` is grid searching for the best parameters by fitting, predicting, and comparing different configs using RMSE.

```
def auto_sarima(store, train, test):
    p = range(0,4)
    d = range(0,3)
    q = range(0,4)
    m = (3,6,12)
    #trend = ['n','c','t','ct']
    
    pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
    
    seasonal_pdqm = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]) for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q, m))]
    
    best_score = float("inf")
    best_order = None
    best_seasonal_order = None

    for param in pdq:
        for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdqm:
            #for t in trend:
                try:
                    mod = SARIMAX(train,
                                  order=param,
                                  seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                  #trend=t,
                                  enforce_invertibility=False,
                                  enforce_stationarity=False)

                    results = mod.fit()
                    preds = results.predict(start=0, end=(len(test)+len(train)-1), dynamic=(len(train)-1))
                    preds = preds[len(train):]
                    error = mean_squared_error(test, preds, squared=False)
                    if error < best_score:
                        #best_score, best_order, best_seasonal_order, best_trend = error, param, param_seasonal, t
                        best_score, best_order, best_seasonal_order = error, param, param_seasonal
                        #print(best_score, best_order, best_seasonal_order, best_trend)
                        print(best_score, best_order, best_seasonal_order)
                except:
                    continue
    
    #store_sarima_dict[store] = list(best_order), list(best_seasonal_order), best_trend, error
    store_sarima_dict[store] = list(best_order), list(best_seasonal_order), error
    print(store_sarima_dict)
```

And the second `sarima_forecasting` is taking those optimal params and simply predicting the results and saving them in a specific format.

```
def sarima_forecasting(store, train, test, store_sarima_dict):
    model = SARIMAX(train,
                    order=(store_sarima_dict[store][0][0], store_sarima_dict[store][0][1], store_sarima_dict[store][0][2]),
                    seasonal_order=(store_sarima_dict[store][1][0], store_sarima_dict[store][1][1], store_sarima_dict[store][1][2], store_sarima_dict[store][1][3]),
                    #trend = store_sarima_dict[store][2],
                    enforce_invertibility=False,
                    enforce_stationarity=False)
    
    results = model.fit(maxiter=300)
    
    forecast_res = list(results.predict(start=0, end=(len(test)+len(train)-1), dynamic=(len(train)-1)))
    
    forecasts = pd.DataFrame(forecast_res)
    forecasts.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    forecasts['DATE'] = df.index
    forecasts['SCALED_ACTUAL_REVENUE'] = df.iloc[:, 0].values
    forecasts.rename(columns={0:'SCALED_FORECAST_REVENUE'}, inplace=True)
    
    train.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
    train.drop('REVENUE', axis=1, inplace=True)
    train['TRAIN_DUMMY'] = 1
    forecasts = forecasts.merge(train, on='DATE', how='left')
    
    test.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
    test.drop('REVENUE', axis=1, inplace=True)
    test['TEST_DUMMY'] = 1
    forecasts = forecasts.merge(test, on='DATE', how='left')
    
    forecasts['ACTUAL_REVENUE'] = sc_in.inverse_transform(forecasts['SCALED_ACTUAL_REVENUE'].values.reshape(-1,1))
    forecasts['FORECAST_REVENUE'] = sc_in.inverse_transform(forecasts['SCALED_FORECAST_REVENUE'].values.reshape(-1,1))
    forecasts['FORECAST_REVENUE'] = forecasts['FORECAST_REVENUE'].round(0)
    forecasts = forecasts[['DATE','TRAIN_DUMMY','TEST_DUMMY','SCALED_FORECAST_REVENUE','SCALED_ACTUAL_REVENUE','FORECAST_REVENUE','ACTUAL_REVENUE']]
    forecasts_list = forecasts.values.tolist()
    
    store_forecast_dict[store] = forecasts_list
    print(store_forecast_dict)
```

However, the majority of the results I'm getting look a bit... Too good.

[image: actual_revenue]

[image: forecasted_and_actual_revenue]

[image: deltas]

In the above example, the out-of-sample predictions begin where the green square is located. The first picture is just the actual revenue graphed. The second is the forecasted revenue and actual revenue graphed. And the 3-month and 12-month deltas (forecasted - actual for x months of the out-of-sample) are pictured as well.

And the optimal params for this example were determined to be:
order = [1, 2, 2] and seasonal_order = [0, 2, 3, 12]

But is it reasonable to expect such exceptional performance for 12 months or 16 months out? Especially when it does better than the 3-month forecast? How does it know that there's going to be a huge spike and how does it model it so closely when it can only use its own predictions for the out-of-sample?

Part of me feels like the SARIMA modelling is simply doing its job. But I'm also wondering if my modelling approach itself is flawed.

Any feedback or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question might also be interesting for the stats stackexchange. You could start by reading about the model and how it does forecasts. Forecasts are always a bit like voodoo and one can't trust the results anyway. The implementation could be wrong or the model could be wrong. Try to compare first with an alternative implementation.

Comment: Great suggestion, I'll post there as well.

Comment: I tried validating the results against Statsmodel's Holt-Winters Exponential Smoothing and the HWES results did much worse. But at the same time, they seem more plausible.

Comment: One way to test predictions is taking historical data, cutting off even more data, predicting on chunks of historical data and comparing with the known past. Any good forecast service should at least be able to correctly predict the known data.

Comment: ^^ I ended up going with a variant of your suggestion earlier today. I'm still not sure what's up with the forecast/predict with SARIMAx and if/how it differs from HWES forecast/predict but I was able to compare the forecast to a completely withheld dataset and it gave me a much better idea of its true performance.